# Books in Springer Math LaTeX template give incomplete entry in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am writing a paper using the Springer template (sn-jnl class) and have a problem regarding the bibliography. The .bib entry is

```
@book{LeVeque1992,
  title = {Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws},
  ISBN = {9783034886291},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8629-1},
  DOI = {10.1007/978-3-0348-8629-1},
  publisher = {Birkh\"{a}user Basel},
  author = {LeVeque,  Randall J.},
  year = {1992}
}
```

that I directly took from doi2bib.org. Unfortunately, the output contains this "???" artefact:
[image]

I have this problem with every book. As required by the template, I'm using natbib with no additional settings.
Has anyone experienced something similar and/or do you know what I am missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `natbib` is a citation management package; it does not directly affect how bibliographic entries are formatted. Do please reveal which bibliography style you employ and with which option(s) you load the `sn-jnl` document class. Incidentally, does replacing the single field `publisher = {Birkh\"{a}user Basel},` with a pair of fields `publisher = {Birkh{\"a}user},` and `address={Basel},` help? (Of course, after changing the bib entry, be sure to run a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.)

Comment: The options for sn-jnl are `sn-mathphys,Numbered`. I'm sorry, I don't quite know what you mean by Bibliography style.... I'm working in Overleaf, if that helps you....

Comment: Wow - stunningly enough, adding the address actually helped! Thank you so much! I will later check if that helps for the other books as well.......

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue has been solved by a suggestion made in a comment, to provide a separate `address` field.